# Mongoid Document where class function value is true or false

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, filter, mongoid

I'm trying to filter a feed of posts. A `Post` and `User` both have a Boolean field `banned_from_feed`.

Post has a function:

```
def banned
    self.banned_from_feed or self.user.banned_from_feed
end
```

Running `Post.all.excludes(:banned => true)` doesn't filter out these documents, as `banned` is not a Mongoid Document field.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a scope:

```
scope :banned, lambda { any_of {:banned_from_feed => true}, {:user.banned_from_feed => true} }
```

Comment: Post has `belongs_to :user` but I'm unable to access the user's banned_from_feed field by :user.banned_from_feed. Other than that, this is one step closer, thank you